# Keyboard on UITextField dismisses but cannot click other UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I have two `UITextFields` that I want to use for logging in, one for the username and one for the password. Before I wasn't able to dismiss the keyboard in the first `UITextField` but I managed to fix that, the problem now is that once it dismisses I cannot click on the other `UITextField` to enter in the password, I am just stuck in the username `UITextField` with the keyboard dismissed, so especially I can't do anything. Any suggestions on how to dismiss the keyboard and then click on the other `UITextField` to enter the information?

```
@interface LoginViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext, usernameField, passwordField;

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self.usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

//error occurs here
[self.usernameField resignFirstResponder]; 
return YES;
}
```

Comment: try to replace [self.usernameField resignFirstResponder]; with [testField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Make sure you connect self.usernameField delegate proper or try to [textField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: sorry guys for some reason it works now, which I cannot explain but now I have another problem, I changed the question, do you mind checking out the updated question

Comment: Check my answer, hope that will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this, this thing will be simple

Set the tag for the textfields

```
usernameField.tag=1;
passwordField.tag=2;
```

Then a delegate method to dismiss keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

 [userNameField resignFirstResponder];
 [passwordField resignResponder];
 }
return YES; 
}
```

Update me the result of this

Comment: This works but in order to dismiss the keyboard i have to press "done" twice, how do I make it so I only have to press it once?

Comment: The tags part helped me distinguish UITextFields so this answer was useful thanks

Comment: ya, u seemed to be a fresher, so refer lots of notes, then, youtube videos will also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your code at `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

Everytime you are opening keyboard for  username field while begin editing.

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if(textField==self.usernameField)
{
 [self.passwordfield becomeFirstResponder];
}

}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  //  [self.usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

//error occurs here
if(textField==self.passwordField)
{
[self.view EndEditing:YES];
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works but in order to dismiss the keyboard i have to press "done" twice, how do I make it so I only have to press it once?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to the above problem is changing the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function to:

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And changing the `textFieldShouldReturn` to the following

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder]; 
return YES;
}
```

The above code allows the user to choose the order of input. That is, the user can input the password first, and then the username. If you want the user to input the username first at all times, you could change the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` to

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        if(textField == self.passwordField && [self.userField.text isEqualToString:@""])
             [self.usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
        else
             [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

This will ensure that the username field is always selected if it is empty. If it is not, then the program will select whichever textfield the user touched, for editing.

I hope this answers your question, though a little late. I think it is an easier way than using and monitoring tags.